# Grails tries to validate encoded password (Spring Security Core)

Tags: spring, validation, grails, spring-security

I spent hours on this problem without finding the solution. Other questions come close but none of the suggested solutions work for me.

I'm running on
- Grails 2.1.1 installed with 
- Groovy 2.0.8 and
- Oracle Java v 1.6.0_45 (also tried with 1.7 already)

I added the Spring Security Core Plugin v 2.0-RC2.
 
I'm a Grails beginner and all I want to do is create a "Runner" with a password using my own password validator.

This is my Runner.groovy domain class (did not change very much from the default Spring Security User template apart from the renaming):

```java
package de.muden.runnerbase

class Runner {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String password
boolean enabled = true
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean passwordExpired

Date dateCreated
Profile profile

public static final int MIN_PASS_LENGTH = 6
public static final int MAX_PASS_LENGTH = 20

static transients = ['springSecurityService']

static constraints = {
    username(size:3..20,unique:true)
    password(nullable:false, blank:false, minSize:6, validator: { passwd, runner ->
        return (passwd != runner.username && validatePasswordInplace(passwd))
    })
    dateCreated()
    profile(nullable:true)
}

static mapping = {
    profile lazy:false
    runs sort:'dateCreated'
    password column: '`password`'
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}

def beforeInsert() {
    encodePassword()
}

def beforeUpdate() {
    if (isDirty('password')) {
        encodePassword()
    }
}

String toString() {
    return "Runner '$username'"
}

protected void encodePassword() {
    password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
}

protected static boolean validatePasswordInplace(String passToValidate) {
    println "VALIDATING PASS $passToValidate"
    return passToValidate ==~ /([A-Za-z0-9äöüÄÖÜß.!\?_-]){$MIN_PASS_LENGTH,$MAX_PASS_LENGTH}/
}

static hasMany = [runs: Run, shoes: Shoe]
}
```

So the validator allows passwords between 6 and 20 characters long, upper and lower case letters, numbers and a few special characters.
Simple unit tests just testing this method work as expected.

Now a simple integration test:

```java
void testValidRunner() {
    Runner r = new Runner(username:'dummy',password:'foobar')
    assertTrue r.validate()   // OK
    assertFalse r.hasErrors()  // OK        
    assertNotNull r.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)     // OK

    Runner foundRunner = Runner.findByUsername("dummy")
    assertNotNull foundRunner         // fails, foundRunner = null
    assertEquals('dummy',foundRunner.username)
}
```

And the console (with -echoOut) says:

```
VALIDATING PASS foobar
VALIDATING PASS $2a$10$Q5RYaDrCFFxdXEqYqV4J2OJWHzgOJZJ3wljqVK1jNP4Sqm6ZUOPam
```

It is obvious that the second validation fails. But why is grails validating the encoded password again? And why doesn't r.validate() complain? Where exactly does that second validation happen?

I have the feeling that I'm doing really basic user password encryption wrong here...

First I thought it had to do with the Spring Security fields "accountExpired" etc. being added and not in the constraints block. But when I remove the custom validator everything works fine.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Below is what I think is going on ...

1. The second validation happens when you call r.save
2. The beforeInsert method is calling the encodePassword method, which is encoding the PW to the long string $2a$10$Q5RYaDrCFFxdXEqYqV4J2OJWHzgOJZJ3wljqVK1jNP4Sqm6ZUOPam
3. That is the string that will be validated and saved in the DB not 'foobar'
4. I believe that your regex does not allow the dollar sign, which is part of the encoded string resulting in the failure.

I do not think that using constraints will work for what you want to do.  You need to validate before it is encoded, so you probably need to add separate validation code (in the domain class or elsewhere) and validate the PW before assigning to the PW field and saving the object.